# sum of unit roots is also unit root

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

A  complex number $\epsilon$ is a  unit root if  $\epsilon^n=1$ for some positive integer $n$.

How would one prove that if $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2,\dots, \epsilon_k$ are all unit roots, and $|\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2+\dots+\epsilon_k|=1$, then $\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2+\dots+\epsilon_k$ is also a unit root ?

I have no clue about it. Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

p.s.  I only know the problem was from a math student who got perfect score on the IMO

Comment: does $\epsilon_i$ include $1$

Comment: Did you mean that $\forall k\ \ n_k=n=\mathrm{const}$ where $\epsilon_k^{n_k}=1$? Or $\exists k_1\ne k_2\ \ n_{k_1}\ne n_{k_2}$?

Comment: @Constructor it seems no difference: $\epsilon_i^{n_i}=1$ then $\epsilon_i^{n_1n_2\dotsb n_k}=1$

Comment: @ziangchen You are right, of course. Thank you.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/126966/can-the-sum-of-two-roots-of-unity-be-a-root-of-unity.

Comment: I think this was answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39856/sums-of-roots-of-unity).